# MATLAB - Google BigQuery via REST API

Tags: matlab, google-bigquery

I'm trying to download data from Big Query Google using REST API.. Everything works fine, however i can't download all selected values but only 350 000 Floats each time. Is there a limit? Is it possible to remove this limit?

api = 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/';
access_token = 
options = weboptions( 'RequestMethod', 'post', 'MediaType', 'application/json','Timeout', Inf);
query=['SELECT '...
'TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(timestamp) as datetime, '...
'VALUEKEY, ' ...
....
'deviceId '...
'WHERE '...
'(_PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(''2023-06-28'') '...
'AND TIMESTAMP(''2023-06-25'')) '...
data = struct('query', query, 'useLegacySql', false);
r = webwrite([api '' access_token], data, options);

limits in MATLAB REST API with Google BIG Query